# Are there shipping company offices like Shunfeng express in Beijing or Shanghai Pudong Airport?

Tags: china, shipping, beijing, shanghai

I would like to ship something within China immediately I arrive at Beijing or Shanghai airport (I am yet to buy the ticket). The problem is that I will not be leaving the airport to any place since I will take a domestic flight immediately I arrive at the airport. Does anyone know if I can find SF-Express or any available shipping company at the airport?

Answer (score 2):

My Chinese is not too great, but the link to locate locations is here: http://www.sf-express.com/cn/sc/dynamic_functions/store/

Answer (score 2):

If you are at the airport, you just need call Shunfeng's service hotline 95338. They will come and pick the express. what you need do is to fill in the destination information and give them service fee (might be 18-20rmb/kg)